# Regular expression matching hashtag, whitespace then characters

Tags: php, regex

Ok, so I've been reading up on regexes, and they're fun!

I've been looking into matching a string like `# 54jsfjk` or `# ffskkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk884587923572957`

Will the following suffice: `/# \w*/i`?

The string I'm trying to replace lives on a single line (there are more lines after), so I guess matching everything after isn't good.

Would making use of the `^` and `$` only choose the single line?

The file I am working with looks sort of like this:

```
HEADER

# stringthatsreplaced

OTHER HEADER
- Stuff
- More Stuff

ANOTHER HEADER
- Even more stuff
- Last stuff
```

Comment: Better to use anchors: `'/^# \w+$/'`

Comment: Yes, it's what I've implemented in the code by now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use the anchors, you need to use the multiline mode as well:

```
/^# \w*$/m
```

<sub>*As rightly pointed out by Robin in the comment, the case insensitive flag isn't required here as `\w` is already case insensitive. It doesn't hurt to use it, but it's not doing anything in this particular regex.</sub>

Otherwise, `^` and `$` will match only at the beginning of the *file/text block* (not line) and `$` will match only at the end of the file/text block.

And I'm not sure if you can have spaces as well, or other characters, but if you do, you will need to use something else than `\w*`. `.*` should be working just as fine to match the whole line that begins with `#`:

```
/^# .*$/m
```

Comment: No need for the `i` flag for either of those solutions, `\w` stands for `[a-zA-Z0-1]` and `.` matches anything.

Comment: @Robin Lol, silly me, yup, they aren't needed in this case. Btw, `\w` stands for `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`.